# No access to public method in interface implementation class (access only to method declarated in interface)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an interface and two implementations of this interface.

1. EmailTokenServiceImpl
2. ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl

Interface contains only one method named `generateToken()`

In one of my implementation class `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl` I have added one more method named `exampleMethod()`.

Now the problem is when I autowired the service having extra method in my controller class I'm not able to call the `exampleMethod()`

Interface Declaration:

```java
    public interface TokenService {

    /**
     * Generate verification token for given user.
     *
     * @param user the user entity
     * @return the verification token
     */
    public VerificationToken generateToken(User user);
    }
```

First Service:

```java
    @Service(value = "emailTokenService")
    public class EmailTokenServiceImpl implements TokenService {

    @Value("${email.token.expiration.hours}")
    private int expirationIn;

    /**
     * Generate Token for email verification {@link EmailVerificationToken}
     * @return VerificationToken token
     */
    @Override
    public EmailVerificationToken generateToken(User user) {
        EmailVerificationToken token = new EmailVerificationToken();
        token.setToken(generateHash());
        token.setExpirationDate(getExpirationDate());
        token.setUser(user);
        return token;
    }
```

Second Service:

```java
    @Service(value = "resetPasswordService")
    public class ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl implements TokenService {

    @Override
    public ResetPasswordToken generateToken(User user) {
        ResetPasswordToken token = new ResetPasswordToken();
        token.setToken(generateHash());
        token.setExpirationDate(getExpirationDate());
        token.setUser(user);
        return token;
    }

    public String exampleMethod() {
        return "example"; 
    }
```

Controller (Trying to access the `exampleMethod()` ):

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class SecurityController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private UserService userService;
    private TokenService resetPasswordService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityController(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider,
            UserService userService,
            TokenService resetPasswordService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.resetPasswordService = resetPasswordService;
    }

 @GetMapping("/reset-password/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> resetPasswordRequest(@PathVariable(value = "token") String token) {
      String example = resetPasswordService.exampleMethod();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Why I'm not able to invoke the `exampleMethod()` method ?

Do I have to declare it in my interface ?

Comment: Little bit more details... Which version of spring you are using ?
Core java behavior - When you want to call a sub-class / implementation class specific method then in that case you have to cast the object first otherwise compiler will give you an error; because which method will be called is decided at run-time because you are using super-type to auto-wire the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The interface `TokenService` doesn't declare the method `exampleMethod()`. So you cannot call that method. You would have to use a cast `((ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl)resetPasswordService).exampleMethod();`, if `resetPasswordService` is an instance of `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl`.

If you add that method to the interface, all implementations of `TokenService` will have to implement that method. For example, `EmailTokenServiceImpl` doesn't declare that method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All your controller knows is that `resetPasswordService` is an implementation of `TokenService`.

You could cast `resetPasswordService` as `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl` but it would be better to instead declare `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl resetPasswordService` explicitly in your constructor.

Don't over-abstract your code. Just explicitly wire in all the necessary implementations of `TokenService` as their implementing classes.  I don't see that there's anything to be gained by treating each different `TokenService` as instances of the interface.

Comment: I declare interface in field: `private TokenService resetPasswordService`
In constructor i do: `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl resetPasswordService` and in constructor body i do: `this.resetPasswordService = resetPasswordService`

But i still have to cast `resetPasswordService` as `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl`
I don't understand what i doing wrong?

Comment: `private TokenService resetPasswordService` tells Java that `this.resetPasswordService` is an implementation of `TokenService`. Assigning an implementation of `ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl` to `this.resetPasswordService` does not change `this.resetPasswordService` to a different type.  An interface is a contract. By declaring `private TokenService resetPasswordService` you have guaranteed that `resetPasswordService` is a `TokenService` and nothing more.  Your declaration should be `private ResetPasswordTokenServiceImpl resetPasswordService`.